# Icedtea in Chrome won't load java applets

Tags: java, google-chrome, openjdk, minecraft

Icedtea in Chrome won't load java applets such as minecraft and runescape. It shows a gray screen instead. I've tried and failed to install the java plugin for chrome and it's left me wondering why icedtea wont's work!?

Comment: what error do you get? how did you try to install it?

Comment: No error, just no java. err, nothing will start using icedtea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have this bug, and what I did was activate the plugin. Go to `chrome://plugins` whilst using chrome and then activate the appropriate plugin(s) for java.

Thanks, mjchopperboy